# How to write a x-path for a button with a value, when the page has same button more than once.

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a button called "checkout" for every sale number(more than once in a page), I have to click based on my sale number. How to write xpath for the please, the sale number should be an input value, it will change frequently.

Below is my source code,

```
"<a target="_self" data-french="procéder au paiement" data-english="Checkout" href="https://staging.christies.com/MyChristies/payments.aspx?AccountNumber=10281372&amp;SaleNumber=17244&amp;PaddleNumber=6001&amp;CCPymtRestricted=N&amp;acRestricted=N&amp;language=en" class="cta checkoutButton">Checkout</a>"
```

Comment: You can use findElement(By.lintext("Checkout") or partialtext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with contains in href, something like below

```
  //a[contains(@href,'SaleNumber=17244')][contains(text(),'Checkout')]
```

pass 17244 as string

```
 //a[contains(@href,'SaleNumber="+passStringHere+"')][contains(text(),'Checkout')]
```

Comment: Worked well. Thank you.